# ListChanged ItemAdded event fires twice when adding a new row to DataGridView

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, bindingsource

I have a simple setup of a DataTable, BindingSource connected to it and a DataGridView bound to the BindingSource. The DataTable is populated with 1 initial row. Then I start to listen to the BindingSource.Listchanged event.

When I start editing a new row in the DataGridView a ListChanged event with ItemAdded type is fired. BindingSource has 2 items and the item added is a row with default values. If I cancel editing I receive a ListChanged ItemDeleted event, what logical so far.

But if I enter the new row I receive just another ItemAdded notification and BindingSource again contains 2 items. So, I have **two** ItemAdded events but only **one** item is added to the underlying list in BindingSource.

What I do now is tracking BindingSource list count and if it has not changed I treat ItemAdded event as "ItemReplace" event. But I'd like to know what is proper way to handle this situation.

I attach code for tracking this event.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler bs.ListChanged, AddressOf OnListChanged
        dt.Columns.Add("ID")
        dt.Columns.Add("Name")
        dt.Rows.Add("1", "Line 1")
        bs.DataSource = dt
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
    End Sub

    Private Sub OnListChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListChangedEventArgs)

        Select Case e.ListChangedType
            Case ListChangedType.ItemAdded
                TextBox1.Text += String.Format("ItemAdded Count:{0} NewIndex:{1}{2}", bs.List.Count, e.NewIndex, vbCrLf)
            Case ListChangedType.ItemDeleted
                TextBox1.Text += String.Format("ItemDeleted Count:{0} NewIndex:{1}{2}", bs.List.Count, e.NewIndex, vbCrLf)
            Case ListChangedType.ItemChanged
                TextBox1.Text += String.Format("ItemChanged Count:{0} NewIndex:{1}{2}", bs.List.Count, e.NewIndex, vbCrLf)
            Case ListChangedType.ItemMoved
                TextBox1.Text += String.Format("ItemMoved Count:{0} NewIndex:{1}{2}", bs.List.Count, e.NewIndex, vbCrLf)
            Case ListChangedType.Reset
                TextBox1.Text += String.Format("Reset Count:{0} NewIndex:{1}{2}", bs.List.Count, e.NewIndex, vbCrLf)
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

**UPDATE** Microsoft sheds some light on the double-firing in its [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist.addnew?view=netframework-4.7.2) on IBindingList:

> When this method is called, you should raise a ListChanged event with the ItemAdded enumeration carrying the appropriate index. The added row is in a state where hitting Esc on a DataGridView control can remove the new row. Raising the ListChanged event with the ItemAdded enumeration a **second** time on this row indicates that the item is now a normal row (not in new state).

So it seems like logic is that after first ItemAdded notification you will receive either second ItemAdded notification (means keep the item) or ItemDeleted notification (means discard previously added item).

But the problem is that when I load data to the bound DataTable with ReadXML method, ListChanged event is raised only once per row.

Some tests show that if IsNew property of the added item is true, then it is a temporary item. That is how I can tell temporary data from final.

Comment: `But I'd like to know what is proper way to handle this situation.`  It's hard to answer a "proper way" question.  If your way works, then it works.  You could also include an If-block in your Select-Case block under ItemAdded: `If Not DataGridView1.Rows(e.NewIndex).IsNewRow Then`

Comment: @LarsTech by "proper" I mean the the way developers at Microsoft .Net team would do it. Checking the row state is indeed an option, but I would do it through the BoundingSource, not DataGridView directly.